# flex-basis affecting size of sibling item in nested flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a nested flex layout.

Here is my codepen link https://codepen.io/mendoncafiles/pen/oNoGbPa

There is a flex container, inside which I have list items. Each list item is a flex, with `I` tag and `SPAN` tag as flex items. The `I` tag has `flex-basis` of 30px.

The text in last list-item is wrapped to next line.
The text is displayed in single line with two options:

1. remove display: flex from wrapping `DIV`
2. Change `flex-basis: 30px` to `width: 30px` to `I` tag.

**Expected:**

[image]

**Issue:**

[image]

Comment: The line doesn't wrap with `flex: 0 0 20px` on the `i`. Not sure what the problem is.  https://codepen.io/mbnyc/pen/XWzeMdN

Comment: @michaelbenjamin - Thanks for checking. Can you change ```flex-basis: 0 0 20px``` to ```flex-basis: 0 0 30px``` for ```i``` and ```flex-basis: 1 1 100px``` to ```flex-basis: 1 1 auto``` for ```span``` tag

Comment: I tried that. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet solved :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the browser is establishing the size of the container before factoring in the full length of the spans.

You can disable `flex-shrink` or use `white-space: nowrap` on the `span`s. But that will cause an overflow.

Consider setting a minimum width on the top level flex container or the `ul`.